# Phonegap_java: duplicate class: org.apache.cordova.BuildConfig

Tags: android, cordova, build

I have downloaded Phonegap from CLI (working on windows7) and made a project from command line

```
phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

and built it

```
phonegap build android
```

When i import project (project/platforms/android) in Intelijj and try to build it, it gives me this error

```
java: duplicate class: org.apache.cordova.BuildConfig
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps that I did to import project in IntelliJ, after I built the application with "cordova build":

> 1. Import project
> 2. select "PROJECT_FOLDER/platforms"
> 3. Import project from external model "Eclipse"
> 4. In select Eclipse project, select all.
> 5. Import JDK and SDK (JDK 1.7 and SDK Android API 17 and 19 in my case)
> 6. Import Android Dependencies From Property Files (Add dependency helloworls --> helloworld-cordovaLib) OK.

At last this build and run without problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

There are an issue with IntelliJ and Maven, maybe you can apply the same solution.
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94901

1.) Delete the "gen", "target" and "out" folders

2.) Revert the changes within the "ipr" and "iml" files

3.) Start IntelliJ 11.1.5 EAP / 12 EAP

4.) Open the pom file

5.) Right click -> "Maven" -> "Reimport"

6.) "Build" -> "Rebuild project"

Comment: I have seen this but i am not sure i understand, cause in my project, i don't have target and out..

Comment: I tried to create a new cordova project and import in intellij, with JDK 1.7, Android version 4.4.2, cordova version 3.4.1-0.1.0 and IntelliJ version 13.1.2. But I couldnt reply the problem, It run ok to me, sorry

Comment: how come you don't have two buildconfig files, one of the project and one in CordovaLib folder?

Comment: I followed this steps: 1. npm install -g cordova 2. cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld 3. import exist project in IntelliJ (this import 2 projects, helloworld and cordovaLib)

Comment: ok and how can you build it then when cordovalibs has its build file

Comment: The steps that I did to import project in IntelliJ, after I built the application with "cordova build": 1. Import project 2. select "PROJECT_FOLDER/platforms" 3. Import project from external model "Eclipse" 4. In select Eclipse project, select all. 5. Import JDK and SDK (JDK 1.7 and SDK Android API 17 and 19 in my case) 6. Import Android Dependencies From Property Files (Add dependency helloworls --> helloworld-cordovaLib) OK. At last this build and run without problem to me.

Comment: If you have more problems, could you test with Android Studio, is IntelliJ in the background. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: It worked! the only thing i did different is to import it from external model Eclipse.
Can you please put it as an answer so i could vote? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A better workaround (tl;dr): Don't do the 'cordova build' step from the Cordova workflow (Getting Started Guide for Android)

We ran into this issue while doing Cordova training for our students. The recommended tool from developer.android.com switched from the Eclipse ADT Bundle to Android Studio, so we made the switch.

Unfortunately, you can't follow the same workflow. The Cordova 'Getting Started' guide for the Android platform spells out the commands to execute from the command line.  But, they are for the Eclipse platform. One step needs to omitted for it to work with Android Studio.

One of the links above (http://www.tricedesigns.com/2013/05/16/phonegap-android-studio/) shows the correct workflow, but if you're used to the Cordova workflow, you may just assume it's the same and complete the steps in the same way. However! Omit the 'cordova build' step.  Building the project (instead of letting Android Studio build it) causes Android Studio to get the error from the question.

The accepted answer above didn't work for us, because when we attempt to import the project, there is no 'Import project from external model "Eclipse"' option.  This, however, worked just fine. Hope this saves you the hours we spent looking for answers/troubleshooting.